# how to install global menu in gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome, globalmenu

How can I install gnome2 global menu? [This one](https://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu) (from google) and not the one we taking [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-gnome-shell-global-menu-in.html).

Thanks.

Comment: You don't, gnome2-global menu was an applet for gnome2 wich is deprecated and no longer maintained.

Comment: is there an alternative?

Comment: Is in beta: https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu